# Arithmetic Operation

Tags: android, arithmetic-expressions

[image]

hello guys I am having this problem. When I enter a score in the editText, I want the app to generate the equivalent in the Textview(w/ red box). But the app crashes with this code.

```
private void calculateEquivalent(){
        double x , y;
        y = Double.valueOf(total_score.toString());
        x = Double.valueOf(editScore.getText().toString());

        if (x >= y * 0.65){
            double equivalent = (Math.round((100 + (72 * (x - y)) / y)));
            String equi = String.valueOf(equivalent);
            textEquivalent.setText(equi);
        } else {
            double equivalent = (Math.round((75 + (23 * (x - y * 0.65)) / y)));
            String equi = String.valueOf(equivalent);
            textEquivalent.setText(equi);
        }
    }
```

Comment: please post the stack trace/ error log

Comment: What is the error message? Maybe you input something that is not a number

Comment: @AndroidWeblineindia here it is https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzRtxsi3HCNWMjNlRFMwM0hOd3M/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @omer727 no sir I didn't input any characters or numbers yet when the app crash

Comment: Your `total_score.toString()` or `editScore.getText().toString()` string returning you empty string.

Comment: before calling this method are you checking if the edittext is empty or not. If editText is empty then please create validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot guys without your suggestions I probably stuck in this problem :)
and then I've come up with this

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_student_quiz);

        TextWatcher inputTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                calculateEquivalent();
            }
        };
        editScore.addTextChangedListener(inputTextWatcher);

    }

private void calculateEquivalent(){
        try {
            y = Double.parseDouble(total_score);
            x = Double.parseDouble(editScore.getText().toString());
            if (x >= y * 0.65){
                double equivalent = (Math.round((100 + (72 * (x - y)) / y)));
                String equi = String.valueOf(equivalent);
                textEquivalent.setText(equi);

            } else {
                double equivalent = (Math.round((75 + (23 * (x - y * 0.65)) / y)));
                String equi = String.valueOf(equivalent);
                textEquivalent.setText(equi);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter a Number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**The error is empty string when convert from string to double**

In this code

```
y = Double.valueOf(total_score.toString());

x = Double.valueOf(editScore.getText().toString());
```

May be total_score.toString() or editScore.getText().toString() was empty

And what is type of total_score variable

Comment: y has a fixed value which is 100 
and x is... yeah it is still empty
and the type of total_score is String

Comment: you can you System.out.println() function to print out two value of total_score.toString() and editScore.getText().toString(). Certainly, both are not empty string

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem when trying to convert empty string to a double. You should check first that the text field is not empty and that it doesn't contain characters by catching  NumberFormatException

Answer (score 0):

As the error log suggests, you need to make sure that you have proper values before you start the calculation.

So before calling this function you need to check for below conditions:

```
try
        {
        if((total_score.toString() != null && !total_score.toString().isEmpty()) && (editScore.getText().toString()!=null && !editScore.getText().toString().isEmpty()))
            {
                y = Double.valueOf(total_score.toString());

                x = Double.valueOf(editScore.getText().toString()); //chances of getting a Numberformat exception if entered value is not a number

                calculateEquivalent();
            }
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e)
        {
        //Toast.makeText(m_context, "You entered a wrong value,Please enter only numeric values", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(Throwable e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Also in your calculateEquivalent(); method, you need to make sure that value of y should not be zero.

Hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

Hey @callmejeo the main problem with the function you wrote above is that you are coverting "NULL" values into String so one thing you can do is that to HANDLE exception.

```
 private void calculateEquivalent(){

       try{
            double x , y;
            y = Double.valueOf(total_score.toString());
            x = Double.valueOf(editScore.getText().toString());

            if (x >= y * 0.65){
                double equivalent = (Math.round((100 + (72 * (x - y)) / y)));
                String equi = String.valueOf(equivalent);
                textEquivalent.setText(equi);
            } else {
                double equivalent = (Math.round((75 + (23 * (x - y * 0.65)) / y)));
                String equi = String.valueOf(equivalent);
                textEquivalent.setText(equi);
            }
}
   catch(Exception e){
         Toast.makeText(this,"Please Enter some value",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
}
```